# Inverses of dihedral group elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, dihedral-groups

I am studying group theory and  I'm having a hard time conceptualizing what the inverse element of an element of the dihedral would be like, on the equilateral triangle, for example.
Any explanation is very well received.

Comment: If you're thinking of the dihedral group as the group of symmetries of an equilateral triangle, then consider some starting position of the triangle $x$. If you look at $g\cdot x$ for some $g$ in the dihedral group, this moves the triangle rigidly while preserving its symmetry. Then $g^{-1}$ is the motion you need to do to get the triangle back into its starting position $x$.

Comment: Just to clarify from the wording of your question:  each element of a (dihedral or other) group should have an inverse; i.e., the group should have an inverse element for each element it has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help to see all of the symmetries of an equilateral triangle, and then writing down the subsequent rotations or reflections required to get back to the original image. 
For the equilateral triangle, its symmetry group is 
$$
\{e, r, r^2, s, rs, r^2s\}
$$ 
where $r$ is a counterclockwise rotation of 120$^\circ$ and $s$ is a reflection across an axis of symmetry (there are other ways to define its dihedral group; this is just one of them). Visually, 
[image]
For example; looking at $r^2s$, we can get it back to the original image by rotating it once, and then reflecting it across the axis of symmetry. See if you buy that first. If you do, then we can say the inverse of $r^2s$ is $sr$ (rotation first, reflection second), which makes sense, because 
$$
(r^2s)(sr) = r^2s^2r = r^2r = e
$$
since $r^3 = e$ and $s^2 = e$. So try to think about the inverses visually, then write them down and check if it makes sense algebraically.